# How can I populate and entity reference field/videos that have been previously migrated to the media library?

Tags: 8, media, migrations

Upgrading from D7 to D8, we previously migrated D7 youtube and vimeo videos to the Drupal 8.8 core media library.  We now are attempting to migrate the Video nodes and their media library video fields (which point to the video or video_url media bundles/types in the media library).

We've been able to get tantalizingly close even to the point where we can use migration_lookup to grab the correct media IDs and even populate a text field on the video node with the correct remote youtube link.  But for the life of me I cannot figure out how to populate the actual media library reference video field.  Here's the migration I've been trying.  The first migration at the top (field_gbz_video_ref) is for the video field on the node (and it doesn't work)--and the bottom is for a simple text field I set up on the node for testing which works great!  I can get the correct media ID, youtube video, link to thumbnail, all of that in the text field but nothing with the top one for the media field.

```
# Non-working entity reference video field
  field_gbz_video_ref/0/target_id: 
        plugin: sub_process
        source: field_gbz_video_ref
        process:
          # Look up the ID of the media entity created by the 'd7_file_entity_vimeo'
          # and 'd7_file_entity_youtube' migrations and store them as pseudo-fields,
          # which we'll need to load the media entity in the 'media_entity'
          # psuedo-field.
          media_id:
            plugin: migration_lookup
            migration:
              - gbz_media_video_remote_vimeo
              - gbz_media_video_remote_youtube
            # We have to make sure to tell the Migrate process not to create stubs
            # for non-existent media entities; without this, we'd get a fatal error
            # in the 'entity_load' plug-in when it tries to load it.
            no_stub: true
            source: fid

          # Load the media entity created by either the 'd7_file_entity_vimeo' or
          # the 'd7_file_entity_youtube' migrations and store it as a pseudo-field.
          # Note that the 'entity_load' plug-in is not in Migrate Plus at the time
          # of writing this migration (2019-06-07), so requires the following patch:
          # https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_plus/issues/3018849#comment-12928073
          media_entity:
            plugin: entity_load
            entity_type: media
            source: '@media_id'
          # Finally, store the media entity's video URL as this field's value.
          value: '@media_entity'


# Working text field that can be populated with the correct video reference info like media ID #
  field_gbz_legacy_video:
        plugin: sub_process
        source: field_gbz_video_ref
        process:
          # Look up the ID of the media entity created by the 'd7_file_entity_vimeo'
          # and 'd7_file_entity_youtube' migrations and store them as pseudo-fields,
          # which we'll need to load the media entity in the 'media_entity'
          # psuedo-field.
          media_id:
            plugin: migration_lookup
            migration:
              - gbz_media_video_remote_vimeo
              - gbz_media_video_remote_youtube
            # We have to make sure to tell the Migrate process not to create stubs
            # for non-existent media entities; without this, we'd get a fatal error
            # in the 'entity_load' plug-in when it tries to load it.
            no_stub: true
            source: fid

          # Load the media entity created by either the 'd7_file_entity_vimeo' or
          # the 'd7_file_entity_youtube' migrations and store it as a pseudo-field.
          # Note that the 'entity_load' plug-in is not in Migrate Plus at the time
          # of writing this migration (2019-06-07), so requires the following patch:
          # https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_plus/issues/3018849#comment-12928073
          media_entity:
            plugin: entity_load
            entity_type: media
            source: '@media_id'

          # Finally, store the media entity's video URL as this field's value.
          # value: '@media_entity/field_media_oembed_video/0/value'
          value: '@media_entity/field_media_oembed_video/0/value'
```

What am I doing wrong?  Here's the EntityLoad.php plug in case that helps:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\migrate_plus\Plugin\migrate\process;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContainerFactoryPluginInterface;
use Drupal\migrate\MigrateExecutableInterface;
use Drupal\migrate\ProcessPluginBase;
use Drupal\migrate\Row;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * Loads an entity.
 *
 * This loads an entity of specified entity type by its ID. The provided array
 * value usually will be passed to the get process plugin to extract field
 * values. It there is no entity with that ID, null is returned,
 * so this must be checked e.g. with the skip_on_empty plugin.
 *
 * For content entities, if a langcode is given, that translation is loaded.
 * The langcode is a reference so can be dynamic.
 *
 * Example:
 *
 * @code
 * process:
 *   _noderef:
 *     plugin: entity_load
 *     source: field_noderef/0/target_id
 *     entity_type: node
 *     langcode: @_langcode
 *   name: "@_noderef/field_name/0/value"
 * @endcode
 *
 * @MigrateProcessPlugin(
 *   id = "entity_load",
 * )
 */
class EntityLoad extends ProcessPluginBase implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {

  /**
   * The entity type manager.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface
   */
  protected $entityTypeManager;

  /**
   * The langcode reference. False if not configured.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $langCodeRef;

  /**
   * The storage for the configured entity type.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageInterface|\Drupal\Core\Entity\RevisionableStorageInterface
   */
  protected $entityStorage;

  /**
   * Flag indicating whether there are multiple values.
   *
   * @var bool
   */
  protected $multiple;

  /**
   * Creates a EntityValue instance.
   *
   * @param array $configuration
   *   A configuration array containing information about the plugin instance.
   * @param string $plugin_id
   *   The plugin_id for the plugin instance.
   * @param mixed $plugin_definition
   *   The plugin implementation definition.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager
   *   The entity type manager.
   *
   * @throws \Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\InvalidPluginDefinitionException
   * @throws \Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException
   * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
   */
  public function __construct(
    array $configuration,
    $plugin_id,
    $plugin_definition,
    EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager
  ) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
    $this->entityTypeManager = $entity_type_manager;

    if (empty($this->configuration['entity_type'])) {
      throw new \InvalidArgumentException("'entity_type' configuration must be specified for the entity_load process plugin.");
    }
    $entity_type = $this->configuration['entity_type'];
    $this->entityStorage = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage($entity_type);

    $this->langCodeRef = isset($this->configuration['langcode']) ? $this->configuration['langcode'] : NULL;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $container->get('entity_type.manager')
    );
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   *
   * @throws \Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\InvalidPluginDefinitionException
   * @throws \Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException
   * @throws \Drupal\migrate\MigrateException
   */
  public function transform($value, MigrateExecutableInterface $migrateExecutable, Row $row, $destinationProperty) {

    $this->multiple = is_array($value);
    if (!isset($value)) {
      return [];
    }
    $ids = $this->multiple ? $value : [$value];
    $entities = $this->loadEntities($ids);

    $langcode = $this->langcodeRef ? $row->get($this->langcodeRef) : NULL;
    $arrays = array_map(function (EntityInterface $entity) use ($langcode) {
      if ($entity instanceof ContentEntityInterface) {
        if ($langcode) {
          $entity = $entity->getTranslation($langcode);
        }
        else {
          $entity = $entity->getUntranslated();
        }
      }
      else {
        if ($langcode) {
          throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Langcode can only be used with content entities currently.');
        }
      }
      return $entity->toArray();
    }, $entities);

    $return = $this->multiple ? array_values($arrays) : ($arrays ? reset($arrays) : []);
    return $return;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function multiple() {
    return $this->multiple;
  }

  /**
   * Load entities.
   *
   * @param array $ids
   *   The entity IDs.
   *
   * @return \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface[]
   *   The entities.
   */
  protected function loadEntities(array $ids) {
    $entities = $this->entityStorage->loadMultiple($ids);
    return $entities;
  }

}
```

[image: The impenetrable entity reference video field]